# SQL: Getting the minute value from calculating current datetime - datetime value from table

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, timestamp

Is there a way to retrieve the minute value from calculating the current time (system clock) to the `DateTime` value from the database

example

```
LogID     Timestamp
1         2012-08-06 23:35
2         2012-08-06 23:39
```

Current system date time is: 2012-08-06 23:50

output should be

```
LogID     Minutes
1         15
2         11
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT LogID, [Timestamp], 
    [Minutes] = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, [Timestamp], CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
  FROM dbo.table_name;
```

Comment: That was ridiculously fast! Thanks.